# Viewing Hive Schema Location Information

Tags: hive, schema

If I create a Hive schema with a explicit location like so:

```
CREATE SCHEMA foo
LOCATION "/home/user/foo";
```

How can I view a description of the information stored about the schema in Hive's metastore, including the location?

Running:

Hive 0.13.0

Hadoop 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive an alias for `SCHEMA` is `DATABASE`, with which you can run:

```
DESCRIBE DATABASE databasename;
```